# Print WYSIWYG content with PHP as HTML

Tags: php, html, wysiwyg

How can I print html code that has been created by a WYSIWYG editor with PHP? When I print it with "echo", then it shows the html code on the website only, rather than interpreting it as html tags.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

> htmlspecialchars_decode — Convert special HTML entities back to characters